# I can't read '0d' on binary hex file when I use ifstream in cpp

Tags: c++, file-io, hex, ifstream

I know '0d' means '\r' in ascii code, but I need to be able to read the data regardless.
However, '0d' is ignored whatever function tried. I've tried fgets(), fread() and ifstream to read the data. However, it seems invisible to those methods. The following is the latest method I've tried.

```
std::ifstream input(argv[1], std::ios::binary);
std::vector <unsigned char> buffer(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input), {});

printf("size %d\n", buffer.size());

for (size_t j = 0; j < 1024; j++)
{        
    printf("%02x , %d\n", buffer[j], j);        
}
```

And the following is the output.

```
size 461027
00 , 0
00 , 1
80 , 2
3f , 3
cc , 4
cd , 5
09 , 6
5c , 7
ff , 8
ff , 9
ff , 10
ff , 11
ff , 12
ff , 13
ff , 14
ff , 15
ff , 16
ff , 17
ff , 18
ff , 19
ff , 20
ff , 21
ff , 22
ff , 23
ff , 24
ff , 25
ff , 26
ff , 27
ff , 28
ff , 29
ff , 30
ff , 31
ff , 32
ff , 33
ff , 34
ff , 35
ff , 36
ff , 37
ff , 38
ff , 39
ff , 40
ff , 41
ff , 42
ff , 43
ff , 44
ff , 45
ff , 46
ff , 47
ff , 48
ff , 49
ff , 50
ff , 51
ff , 52
ff , 53
ff , 54
ff , 55
ff , 56
ff , 57
c0 , 58
a8 , 59
0a , 60
33 , 61
00 , 62
00 , 63
64 , 64
16 , 65
48 , 66
```

And here are the data that the actual file has:
[image]

I'd really appreciate if anyone knows how to do it.

(P.S) I really wish to upload the actual hex binary file here but don't know how to do it. T.T

Comment: Which operating system are you using and which compiler?

Comment: Works fine for me with Linux/gcc.

Comment: I'm using gcc compiler on windows.

Comment: Which one? mingw? cygwin? wsl?

Comment: It is mingw. Shouldn't have a problem, right?

Comment: Code looks fine to me. I don't have that combination at hand to experiment, but maybe someone else does.

Comment: could be skip white space flag. if set then \r is maybe considered a space character

Comment: @KermittheFrog `std::istreambuf_iterator` doesn't care about that flag. Otherwise `0a` (`\n`) would be getting skipped, too. `std::istream_iterator` uses the flag, though.